# Firefox extension to make exceptions for showing images in Firefox?

Tags: images, web-browser, firefox, content-filtering

I know how to use `about:config` to block showing images in Firefox; but, for some websites, I need images to be shown; what Firefox extension will allow me to make these exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use uBlock Origin ([Firefox Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)). You can reenable images in the Firefox config again, if you choose this solution.

After you installed it, go to settings:
[image]

Then enable "I'm an advanced user":
[image]

The menu of uBlock Origin is now "advanced" (it's too in the previous screenshots):
[image]

Column 1 is for global rules, column 2 for local (domain specific) ones. Forbid loading of images globally (yellow circle). Then you can reenable the loading of images per domain in the column 2.

Optionally save (lock icon) and refresh the page. If you don't save the changes, they will only be applied in the current session:
[image]

Comment: Can I do this using firefox itself (without using add-on)? I mean, disabling images using `about:config` globally, then enabling them per case.

Comment: I don't know a way. However since I recommend everyone to use uBlock Origin anyway, it's not a big issue in my eyes. Is there a specific reason, you want to disable images in the config?

Comment: Actually no, there is no specific reason except that some extensions threaten privacy, therefore I was preferring not to use them as much as possible. Anyway, I installed ublock origin and it is fine.

Comment: Fair point. However I'm convinced that if there would be one single add-on which actually improves privacy, it's uBlock Origin.